# Generating unique number in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table containing following column

```
 APP_ID(VarChar),USER_ID(VarChar), ROLE_ID(Number),....
   app1                user1          3
   app1                user2          3
   app2                user2          4
   app2                user3          3
   app3                user1          7
```

As you can see there is no ID field and i cannot add it.

if i use below query it is giving me unique and same number every time i use below query

```
SELECT owa_opt_lock.checksum(a.APP_ID || a.USER_ID || a.ROLE_ID) as ID
```

I want to know it is safe to use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  You might have a collision.  For instance, these two rows would have the same id (app1user212):

```
app1 user2  12
app1 user21  2
```

This is easily fixed by using delimiters.  So, the following would be fine with most tables:

```
(a.APP_ID || '|' ||  a.USER_ID || '|' || a.ROLE_ID) as ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the `rownum`?

```
UPDATE table
SET table_key = rownum;
```

Comment: no i cant , because if where clasue is specified then rownumber will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

collision might happen if two rows have same values(it may).

why don't you try using a row_number() analytic function instead.

```
  try adding: row_number() over(order by NULL).
```

It generates a unique no series(actually its the row number)